# Is there a way to verify which Unusual Gems that I already have?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have one less Unusual Gem than I expect and I don't want to go through the tedium of revisiting each location. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_Stone_Unturned#Finding_the_Gems lists each Unusual Gem's RefID, so it would seem the task is to check the RefID of each of my Unusual Gems.

How do I do check the RefIDs of my Unusual Gems? Or is there an easier way to check?

I tried "drop 7f956", but I get an error:

> Invalid inventory object '7f956' for parameter ObjectID.

I also tried the second RefID, adding the player. prefix, adding 1 (quantity) after the RefID, making sure there was no RefID highlighted in console, and enclosing the RefID in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of mods, there's [Stones of Barenziah Quest Markers](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9385/?) (and [Stones of Barenziah DROPPABLE plus Quest Markers](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14525/?)). Once it's activated, check the world map.